# Whats the difference between = and == in java?

Tags: java, operators

I know that `==` means equal to but I cannot figure out what `=` means.

Comment: The two are different because C (which Java is based on) allows assignment in many ways, including in expressions that return a boolean.  If they were the same, you could not do that.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it can be trivially found by looking at the official tutorials. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/op1.html

Answer (score 3):

A single `=` is assignment. A value is assigned to a variable.

```
int a = 1; // <-- assign 1 to a.
```

[JLS-15.26.1. Simple Assignment Operator `=`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.26.1) says (in part)

> A compile-time error occurs if the type of the right-hand operand cannot be converted to the type of the variable by assignment conversion ([§5.2](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.2)).

The `==` is the equality operator, [JLS-15.21. Equality Operators](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.21) says (in part),

> The operators `==` (equal to) and `!=` (not equal to) are called the *equality operators*.

Answer (score 2):

`=` means [assignment operator](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/op1.html) which assigns the value on its right to the operand on its left whereas `==` (Equal to) means equality check.

Say, you want to assign `1` into a variable `i`, so you have to write:

```
i = 1;
```

But if you want to check whether the value of `i` is `1` or not, you have to check:

```
if (i == 1) {
//do something
} else {
// do something else
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`=` is the assignment operator. E.g., `a = 5` means assigning the value of `5` to the variable `a`.

Answer (score 0):

the operator "=" assign the value to a certain instance

**but**

an operator "==" means a certain instance has a value of something

example

```
  x = 2; //It means x is 2
  x == 2; //means x has a value of 2
```

Answer (score 0):

`=` is the assignment operator which is used to assign a value to a variable, property or fields. While `==` is used to check a condition for example in a `if` condition

Answer (score 0):

```
int houseAddress = 1;
```

This means that the variable houseAddress is given the value of 1, so you can think of this as the address of the house is equal to 1;

```
if(houseAddress == 1){
//do something
}
```

This code is saying whether houseAddress is equal to 1 this would return TRUE or FALSE in this case we know that houseAddress is 1 so it return TRUE.

Hope this helps its missing a few technical detail which might confuse you so its missed out.